# Can't find Instantiation of objects (response, request, application) in java web app

Tags: java, eclipse, web, tomcat7

I have to work on a java web application which someone else did. Since I'm new to java web development, I scanned the code some and stumbled over some instantiated objects where I can not find the reference to where it is instantiated, i.e. in a `.jsp` page

```
    ...some includes
    UserFactory uf=null;

    if (application.getAttribute("userFactory") == null){
    ...
    strUser=request.getParameter("user");
    pw=request.getParameter("pw");
    ...
```

(notice `application, request, response`)

Now I realise that it could have been declared in some of the includes, and I did go through them all but could not find the declaration (possible though that I did oversee it).
Now the question is:
Are these objects somehow globally instantiated by tomcat (if so where can I find that) and if that is not the case, how would one go about finding them in a fairly big project (btw I'm using Eclipse JUNO) (i.e. like a feature of eclipse to find the instantiation), preferably without looking manually through every single include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JSPs those variables are called "implicit objects". Find all implicit objects available in JSPs here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaij:

> Implicit Objects
>
> The JSP expression language defines a set of implicit objects:
>
> - pageContext: The context for the JSP page. Provides access to various objects including:
>
>   - servletContext: The context for the JSP page’s servlet and any web components contained in the same application. See Accessing the Web Context.
>   - session: The session object for the client. See Maintaining Client State.
>   - request: The request triggering the execution of the JSP page. See Getting Information from Requests.
>   - response: The response returned by the JSP page. See Constructing Responses.
>
> In addition, several implicit objects are available that allow easy access to the following objects:
>
> - param: Maps a request parameter name to a single value
> - paramValues: Maps a request parameter name to an array of values
> - header: Maps a request header name to a single value
> - headerValues: Maps a request header name to an array of values
> - cookie: Maps a cookie name to a single cookie
> - initParam: Maps a context initialization parameter name to a single value
>
> Finally, there are objects that allow access to the various scoped variables described in Using Scope Objects.
>
> - pageScope: Maps page-scoped variable names to their values
> - requestScope: Maps request-scoped variable names to their values
> - sessionScope: Maps session-scoped variable names to their values
> - applicationScope: Maps application-scoped variable names to their values

Answer (score 0):

They're variables provided for all JSP pages by the servlet engine. With servlets you'll get `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` passed in to the `doXXX` methods, and they're also available during JSP processing.